# LARAVEL: Showing the slug in URL instead of ID - List of Categories

Tags: php, laravel, frameworks, laravel-5

In the URL I want to show the `slug` instead of `ID`. I've tried this :

```
{{ url('/produits/'.$category->slug) }}
```

but it doesn't return any results. What can I do?

Thanks in advance!

**web.php**:

```
Route::get('/produits/{id?}', 'Controller@produits');
```

**Controller**:

```
public function produits($id = null){
      if($id){
        $produits = Post::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
                    ->whereStatus('PUBLISHED')
                    ->whereCategoryId($id)
                    ->take(10)->get();
      }else {
        $produits = Post::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
                    ->whereStatus('PUBLISHED')
                    ->take(10)->get();
      }
        $categories = Category::all();
        return view('Mywebsite.produits', ['id' => $id, 'mesProduits' => $produits, 'mesCategories' => $categories]);
    }
```

**Products.php**:

```html
    <nav id="nav-top">
      <ul>
        <li> <a href="{{ url('/produits') }}">Tous les produits</a></li>
        @foreach ($mesCategories as $category)
        <li><a href="{{ url('/produits/'.$category->id) }}">{{ $category->name }} -({{ $category->posts->count() }})</a></li>
        @endforeach
      </ul>
    </nav>

    <div class="lx-products-list lx-bloc-content">
      <div class="lx-products-items">
        @foreach ($mesProduits as $produit)
        <div class="lx-g4 lx-g5-to-g2">
          <div class="lx-products-item">
            <a href="Produit/39.html">
              <div class="lx-products-item-img">
                <a href="{{ url('/produit/'.$produit->slug) }}">
                  <img src="{{ asset('/storage/'.$produit->image) }}" />
                </a>
              </div>    
              <h4>{{ $produit->category->name }}</h4>   
              <div class="lx-products-item-detail">
                <h2 class="haha2"><i style="color:#fdd043;" class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i><a href="{{ url('/produit/'.$produit->slug) }}">{{ str_limit($produit->title, 30) }}</a></h2>

                <p class="para">
                  <ins>
                  {{ $produit->prix }}  درهم

                  </ins>    
                </p>

              </div>    
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
        @endforeach

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="lx-clear-fix"></div>
    </br></br></br>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: could you kindly show us the definition of the `$category` variable? it seems it doesnt have any `sluG` property

Comment: all what i did is in the code above..

Comment: @foreach ($mesCategories as $category)
      <li><a href="{{ url('/produits/'.$category->id) }}">{{ $category->name }} -({{ $category->posts->count() }})</a></li>
      @ endforeach

Comment: I think the `slug` property belongs to the `$produit` object, and not the `$category`? I'm asking for your definition of the `$mesCategories`, or to simply put it, may I know what are the columns or properties of that object

Comment: -> categories: ID, Order, Name, slug, created_at
->  products: ID, author_id, category_id, slug, body..

Comment: ok copy, thank you for that, now going back to your main question: you said that this code `{{ url('/produits/'.$category->slug) }}` isn't working right? may you kindly use the `dd()` debugging tool to them? like try this code `dd(url('/produits/'.$category->slug))` so we can see what's the content? coz I doubt that it is empty, you've mentioned that the **slug** really does belong to the **categories** table

Comment: i think the problem is in public function produits(){} because i make if($id){}.... see the code above

Comment: dude, kindly screenshot it, the URL you gave is only accessible for your local storage

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/axKTY3a.png

Comment: oh? so it's working perfectly fine, may we recap what was your problem again? kindly elaborate it please, now I'm quite confused with what really is your problem

Comment: If you want to show the slug in your url change your route like so : `Route::get('/produits/category-{id?}', 'ZamzamController@produits');`

Comment: @JueViole17 
when i click in categorie button .. i want to show products related of categorie selected + in the url i want to show categorie slug instead of ID

screenshot: https://i.imgur.com/fehGxfc.png

Answer (score 0):

According to our discussion in the comment section here's what I deduced

In your **web.php** file, you may add this route to specifically pinpoint to your categories page

```
Route::get('/produits/category-{id?}', 'ZamzamController@produits');
```

The `{id}` portion here tells that it can be changed anytime or may be optional

Comment: redirect me to : Error Page: 404
Not Found Page

Comment: when i click in categorie button .. i want to show products related of the categorie selected + in the url i want to show categorie slug instead of ID..  screenshot: i.imgur.com/fehGxfc.png

Comment: what are the sample contents of your `$category->slug` code? are they like **category-1** or **category-2** and so on? or are they just numbers?

Comment: category-1, category-2, ...
categories Table (screenshot): https://i.imgur.com/kFimEBQ.png

Comment: if you just added what I answered earlier, try to refresh your laravel app, Ctrl + C in your running server to stop, then type `php artisan optimize` to remove all the cache, then run again `php artisan serve`

Comment: have you updated your **web.php** file and added this `Route::get('produits/category-{id?}', 'ZamzamController@produits');` ?

on your view in your link, have you updated your code there to in the anchor tags' href to be `url('produits/'.$category->slug)` ?

Answer (score 0):

For Your Route

```
Route::get('/produits/{id?}', 'Controller@produits');
```

You can get it as below with parameter.

```
$url = action('Controller@produits', ['id' => $MyWebsite->id]);
```

With above way you are showing "$MyWebsite->id", Just change it with Slug ($MyWebsite->slug) and you are ready to go.

Reference : https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/helpers#method-action

Hope, I understand your question well, let me know if any doubts